# List which users modified the personal view of a page and when in SharePoint 2010

Tags: auditing

I am looking for a way to identify when a specific user  customized the personal view of a page in SharePoint 2010. Can this info be obtained in some way? Can an admin get a report listing all the personal view modification users created on a web site?